# Infix evaluation in Python

Tags: python, infix-operator

I am trying to convert the code here http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/expression-evaluation/ to python. However, I am running into some trouble and can't figure out.

```
class evaluateString:

def evalString(self,expression):
    valueStack = []
    opStack = []
    i=0
    while(i<len(expression)):
        if(expression[i] == ' '):
            continue
        if(expression[i]>='0' and expression[i] <= '9'):
            charNumber = [] #for storing number
            while(i<len(expression) and expression[i]>='0' and expression[i] <= '9'):
                charNumber.append(expression[i])
                i+=1
            valueStack.append(int(''.join(charNumber)))

        elif (expression[i]=='('):
            opStack.append(expression[i])

        elif (expression[i]==')'):
            while(opStack[-1]!='('):
                valueStack.append(self.applyOperation(opStack.pop(),valueStack.pop(),valueStack.pop()))
                opStack.pop()
        elif(expression[i]=='+'or expression[i]=='-'or expression[i]=='*'or expression[i]=='/'):
            while( (len(opStack)!=0) and ( self.opPrecedence(expression[i],opStack[-1]) ) ):
                valueStack.append(self.applyOperation(opStack.pop(),valueStack.pop(),valueStack.pop()))
                opStack.append(expression[i])
        i = i + 1

    while(len(opStack)!=0):
        valueStack.append(self.applyOperation(opStack.pop(),valueStack.pop(),valueStack.pop()))

    return valueStack.pop()


def applyOperation(self,op,a,b):
    if op=='+':
        return a+b
    elif op=='-':
        return a-b
    elif op=='*':
        return a*b
    elif op=='/':
        return a/b
    else:
        return 0

def opPrecedence(self,op1,op2):
    if (op2 == '(' or op2 == ')'):
        return False
    if ((op1 == '*' or op1 == '/') and (op2 == '+' or op2 == '-')):
        return False
    else:
        return True

a = evaluateString()
print(a.evalString("(5+7)"))
```

I am able to get the right numbers in the valueStack. However, there seems to be problem in the last two elseif. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done some fixes and it works for some operations. But I haven't tested it for all cases. Also, operations are only integers, no floats (e.g. check last output below).

```
class evaluateString:

  def evalString(self,expression):
    valueStack = []
    opStack = []
    i=0

    while(i<len(expression)):
        if(expression[i] == ' '):
            continue
        if(expression[i]>='0' and expression[i] <= '9'):
            charNumber = [] #for storing number
            j = i
            while(j<len(expression) and expression[j]>='0' and expression[j] <= '9'):
                charNumber.append(expression[j])
                j += 1

            i = (j-1)
            valueStack.append(int(''.join(charNumber)))

        elif (expression[i]=='('):
            opStack.append(expression[i])

        elif (expression[i]==')'):
            while(opStack[-1]!='('):
                valueStack.append(self.applyOperation(opStack.pop(),valueStack.pop(),valueStack.pop()))
            opStack.pop()
        elif(expression[i]=='+'or expression[i]=='-'or expression[i]=='*'or expression[i]=='/'):
            while( (len(opStack)!=0) and ( self.opPrecedence(expression[i],opStack[-1]) ) ):
                valueStack.append(self.applyOperation(opStack.pop(),valueStack.pop(),valueStack.pop()))
            opStack.append(expression[i])
        i = i + 1

    while(len(opStack)!=0):
        valueStack.append(self.applyOperation(opStack.pop(),valueStack.pop(),valueStack.pop()))

    return valueStack.pop()


  def applyOperation(self,op,a,b):
    if op=='+':
        return a+b
    elif op=='-':
        return b-a
    elif op=='*':
        return a*b
    elif op=='/':
        return b/a
    else:
        return 0

  def opPrecedence(self,op1,op2):
    if (op2 == '(' or op2 == ')'):
        return False
    if ((op1 == '*' or op1 == '/') and (op2 == '+' or op2 == '-')):
        return False
    else:
        return True

a = evaluateString()
print(a.evalString("8*12"))        #prints 96
print(a.evalString("(122-434)"))   #prints -312
print(a.evalString("(232+12)/2"))  #print 122
print(a.evalString("232/12+2"))    #prints 21
```

Answer (score 1):

In python eval() will evaluate infix expressions

```
print(eval("(5+7)/2"))
```

it will print the evaluated infix expression value as 6.